# JAXB Not Marshalling SOAP Response

Tags: soap, jaxb, spring-ws

so I'm trying to marshall my soap response with JAXB and spring-ws webservicetemplate and it just isn't working here is my pertinent code

SoapUI Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <getAccountProductsResponse xmlns="http://CellucomPosa/">
     <getAccountProductsResult>
        <CellucomPOSA xmlns="">
           <Product>
              <ProductID>280</ProductID>
              <ProductName>AT&amp;T $15</ProductName>
              <Discount>18</Discount>
              <Price>15.00</Price>
              <ProdType>PINRTR</ProdType>
           </Product>
           <Product>
              <ProductID>281</ProductID>
              <ProductName>AT&amp;T $25</ProductName>
              <Discount>18</Discount>
              <Price>25.00</Price>
              <ProdType>PINRTR</ProdType>
           </Product>
        </CellucomPOSA>
     </getAccountProductsResult>
  </getAccountProductsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is spring context

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="cellucomposa"/>

 <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://Service.asmx"/>
</bean>
```

here are the object in cellucomposa

```
package cellucomposa;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="getAccountProductsResponse")
public class GetAccountProductsResponse
{

    @XmlElement(name="getAccountProductsResult", type=GetAccountProductsResult.class)
    private GetAccountProductsResult getAccountProductsResult;

    public GetAccountProductsResult getGetAccountProductsResult ()
    {
        return getAccountProductsResult;
    }

    public void setGetAccountProductsResult (GetAccountProductsResult getAccountProductsResult)
    {
        this.getAccountProductsResult = getAccountProductsResult;
    }
   }

package cellucomposa;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="getAccountProductsResult")
public class GetAccountProductsResult
{

    @XmlElement(name="CellucomPOSA", type=CellucomPOSA.class)
    private CellucomPOSA CellucomPOSA;

    public CellucomPOSA getCellucomPOSA ()
    {
        return CellucomPOSA;
    }

    public void setCellucomPOSA (CellucomPOSA CellucomPOSA)
    {
        this.CellucomPOSA = CellucomPOSA;
    }
}

package cellucomposa;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlRootElement(name="CellucomPOSA")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CellucomPOSA {

    @XmlElement(name="Product", type=Product.class)
    private Product[] Product;

    public Product[] getProduct ()
    {
        return Product;
    }

    public void setProduct (Product[] Product)
    {
        this.Product = Product;
    }

}

package cellucomposa;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {

    @XmlElement(name="Price")
    private String Price;

    @XmlElement(name="ProductID")
    private String ProductID;

    @XmlElement(name="ProductName")
    private String ProductName;

    @XmlElement(name="Discount")
    private String Discount;

    @XmlElement(name="ProdType")
    private String ProdType;

    public String getPrice ()
    {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice (String Price)
    {
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    public String getProductID ()
    {
        return ProductID;
    }

    public void setProductID (String ProductID)
    {
        this.ProductID = ProductID;
    }

    public String getProductName ()
    {
        return ProductName;
    }

    public void setProductName (String ProductName)
    {
        this.ProductName = ProductName;
    }

    public String getDiscount ()
    {
        return Discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount (String Discount)
    {
        this.Discount = Discount;
    }

    public String getProdType ()
    {
        return ProdType;
    }

    public void setProdType (String ProdType)
    {
        this.ProdType = ProdType;
    }
}
```

Here is the service implementation that is making the request

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.oxm.XmlMappingException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import cellucomposa.GetAccountProductsResponse;

@Service
public class TcetraServiceImpl implements TcetraService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TcetraServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    @Override
    public GetAccountProductsResponse getProducts(GetAccountProducts request) {
        GetAccountProductsResponse response = (GetAccountProductsResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Request Goes through no problem, the response maps to the pojo no problem without any errors but the CellucomPOSA element is always null, even though the soapui response shows otherwise and the request object is exactly the same for the soapui and what's fed into the webservicetemlate. Any idea what may be going wrong here?

Comment: Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Could it be something related to the namespace, or package-info.  It looks like the response somehow has a different namespace for  <CellucomPOSA xmlns="">, where as root node getAccountProductsResponse namespace: http://CellucomPosa/

And all the objects are in the same package.  How are the namespaces defined?